# AutoHotkey causing control key to get stuck

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, modifier-key

I have several situations when my control key gets stuck, and it happens only when I have AutoHotkey running. This happens with multiple different modifier keys including the control (^), windows (#), and alt (!) keys.

Similar problems have been posted several times before:
[1](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/121292-control-key-getting-stuck-after-script-runs/),
[2](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/3248-stuck-ctrl-key/page-2),
[3](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98025-ctrl-key-stuck/). Some solutions exists, and [the one suggested here partially helped me](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/88715-control-key-getting-stuck/) (decreased the frequency of the problem), but the control key still gets stuck occasionally. Things I have tried include [#InstallKeybdHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_HotkeyModifierTimeout.htm).

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to prevent this problem?
2. Is there a good way to have AutoHotkey monitor when keys are stuck (eg automatically notice when keys have been held for >10s) and fix this as soon as it happens?

I have tried everything suggested above, and created my own version of a StuckKeyUp function [(as suggested here)](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=19711):

```
StuckKeyUp(){
sleep 300 
send {<# up} 
send {># up} 
send {# up} 
send {+ up} 
send {<+ up} 
send {! up} 
send {<! up} 
send {>! up} 
send {^<^^>! up} 
send {^<^>! up} 
send {^ up} 
send {Ctrl down} 
send {Ctrl up}

Send {§ up}         
Send {Shift Up}
Send {LShift Up}
Send {RShift Up}
Send {Alt Up}
Send {LAlt Up}
Send {RAlt Up}
Send {Control Up}
Send {LControl Up}  
Send {<^ down}      
Send {<^ Up}        ; solves some issues, but not all
Send {>^ down}      
Send {>^ Up}        
Send {RControl Up}
Send {LControl Up}
Send {LWin Up}
Send {RWin Up}
sleep 100 
; reload, ; Avoid - Reloading AutoHotkey File causes functions depending on this function to break
return 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the other answers and in my original answer:

Among other [debugging methods](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#debug) you can try

- [#HotkeyModifierTimeout](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_HotkeyModifierTimeout.htm) affects the behavior of hotkey modifiers:
  Ctrl, Alt, Win, and Shift.
- Install the keyboard hook by adding the line [#InstallKeybdHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_InstallKeybdHook.htm).
- Use the [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) method.
- Put this code at specific positions in your script (within hotkey
  definitions that send the control key or in a timer) and look in the
  KeyHistory (after closing the message box) in which situations the
  key gets stuck:

```
If GetKeyState("Ctrl")           ; If the OS believes the key to be in (logical state),
{
    If !GetKeyState("Ctrl","P")  ; but the user isn't physically holding it down (physical state)
    {
        Send {Ctrl Up}
        MsgBox,,, Ctrl released
        KeyHistory
    }
}
```

To cover all modifier keys you can use

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#NoEnv
#InstallKeybdHook
SendMode Input

Keys := "LControl,RControl,LAlt,RAlt,LWin,RWin,LShift,RShift"
SetTimer, ReleaseKeys, 500 

; ....

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===


; Your hotkeys here

; ....

ReleaseKeys:
    Loop, parse, Keys, `,
    {
        If GetKeyState(A_LoopField)           ; If the OS believes the key to be in (logical state)
        {
            If !GetKeyState(A_LoopField,"P")  ; but the user isn't physically holding it down (physical state)
            {
                Send {%A_LoopField% Up}
                MsgBox,,, %A_LoopField% released
                KeyHistory
            }
        }
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem (with only Ctrl ever getting stuck), and the fix for me was to use #MenuMaskKey at the top of the script:

```
;; Avoid Ctrl getting stuck in down state, even when not physically pressed:
#MenuMaskKey vkFF
```

Background info from https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm

> The mask key is sent automatically to prevent the Start menu or the active window's menu bar from activating at unexpected times.
>
> The default mask key is Ctrl.
>
> ...
>
> If the system was to detect only a Win or Alt keydown and keyup with no intervening keypress, it would usually activate a menu. To prevent this, the keyboard or mouse hook may automatically send the mask key.

Answer (score 2):

I added #InstallKeybdHook and all was well. See below for details.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_HotkeyModifierTimeout.htm

Comment: This is a solution that works for some cases, although not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

While user3419297's answer is very good, I think the `blind keyup` call is not what fixes the problem.

It appears that the `KeyHistory` command causes the keys to be released.

When I used a version of user3419297's script without `KeyHistory`, it never worked for me. In contrast, invoking `KeyHistory` alone has been sufficient to resolve the problem for me every time it has occured.

Answer (score 1):

This problem suddenly started occurring in a script that had been working without a hitch for years and to which I had made no changes. FWIW it started after a Windows update that seems to have slightly slowed down both AHK and python scripts that send keystrokes to applications. Which everyone seems to say can't happen but I know what I see. Anyhow, I tried everything I could find and nothing worked until I put this at the start of my script:

```
^T:: ;Script starts here
    Sleep, 500
    Send {LCtrl Up}
    ;Script continues and Ctrl is no longer pressed :)
```

Sorry I don't have a precise technical explanation for why this works. I'm guessing that I'm not letting go of the Ctrl key fast enough when I press my hotkey (in this case Ctrl-T), but that it somehow hasn't quite registered with AHK. Whatever the case, that little pause before sending the key up seems to work every time. The 500 ms was arbitrary; it works and I haven't bothered trying to make it any shorter. No more pressing Ctrl after every script, yay!

Answer (score 0):

Use [KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/KeyWait.htm) if you use AutoHotKey v2.

In **AutoHotkey v2**, there is a useful function [KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/KeyWait.htm). It solves these stuck problems exclusively. Before I saw it I've tried `Send "{Ctrl up}"`, waiting for seconds but neither working, until I find KeyWait in
Official document. The similar function appears to [ClipWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/ClipWait.htm).

BTW, I would like to share my codes, rewrite from another LaTeX AHK codes. It can add brackets (In my code they're braces) on both sides:

```
^0::{
    KeyWait "Control"
    ClipBackup := ClipboardAll()
    A_Clipboard := ""
    SendInput "^x"
    Sleep 50
    selection := A_Clipboard
    SendInput "{{}{}}{Left}{Text}" selection
    Sleep 50
    len := StrLen(StrReplace(selection, "`r`n", "`n"))
    ; MsgBox "String '" selection "' has length " len
    Sleep 5 * len
    SendInput "{Left " len "}"
    Sleep 5 * len
    SendInput "+{Right " len "}"
    A_Clipboard := ClipBackup
    Return
}
```

Hope these can help you.