# Using AutoHotKey to temporarily disable stuck modifier keys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to temporarily disable all modifier keys if it seems like one or more of them has become 'stuck' - basically, I need the opposite of Windows' StickyKeys.

I'm working with a Windows tablet (ie. no physical keyboard) with a faulty input device, and it sometimes just jams a bunch of modifier keys, with no predictable trigger. Until I have time to actually troubleshoot the (potentially hardware-level) bug, this script will be a stopgap.

I just need a few seconds to sleep and unsleep the system, since that usually smacks input back into order - unfortunately, the stuck modifier keys interfere with the machine's normal sleep button behavior.

I'm trying to work with the ctrl key first, just to get the concept working, then test for the other modifiers later.

```
TimerVar := 0
CtrlIsStuck := False

Loop {
CtrlKeyPhysicallyDown := GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P")
If CtrlKeyPhysicallyDown
TimerVar++
Else
TimerVar := 0
If TimerVar > 1 ; TODO: make sane before deploy
{
CtrlIsStuck := True
Break
}

Sleep, 500 ; TODO: make sane before deploy
}

#If CtrlIsStuck

ToolTip, Stuck keys detected; jamming for 15 seconds. Use Sleep button now.

SetTimer, DoReload, 15100

Hotkey, Ctrl, DoNothing
Send, {Ctrl Up}

Sleep 15000

DoReload:
Reload

DoNothing:
Return
```

I expect this to check in a loop to see if the ctrl key has been held for a span of time, and if it has, bind ctrl to something that does nothing, claim ctrl has been physically released, then wait for a bit.

The 'check if it's held' logic is working, but once it gets past that `#If` line, things start behaving in a way that, after reading the manual for a while, I still don't understand. While it definitely runs, the Hotkey statement doesn't seem to do anything useful, and the SetTimer line effectively behaves redundantly; I suspect I'm missing something obvious about AutoHotKey's script flow, but I'm unsure what.

Comment: The #If-directive is only used for creating context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings. Try **If** instead or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49034365/3419297).

Comment: Tried that - while it works a bit smoother this way, ctrl still doesn't seem to get remapped.